# How to get table rowcount in DAX Studio

Tags: dax, rowcount, daxstudio

I'm trying to compare the column count of two tables, one in SSMS and one in DAX Studio, but I've never worked with DAX or Dax Studio before.

In SSMS, I ran `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable` to see the rowcount.

In DAX Studio, I ran `COUNTROWS(MyTable)` but it produced this error:

```
The syntax for '<pii>COUNTROWS</pii>' is incorrect.
```

I know there's probably something I need to add to make a valid query but can't find it. How can I query the row number of a table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Youre using dax studio. it can only return table expressions
So you need to create a table in your dax expression.

like this :

```
EVALUATE
ROW("RowCount", COUNTROWS(MyTable))
```